# Best solution for restaurant menu and receipt

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I recently got this question.

"
I've been to a restaurant to order some food, but I've forgotten what I ordered in the past. I only remember how much money I spent.

From the following menu, and list of receipt values, determine what I could have ordered.
'''

primary_menu = {
'veggie sandwich': 6.85,
'extra veggies': 2.20,
'chicken sandwich': 7.85,
'extra chicken': 3.20,
'cheese': 1.25,
'chips': 1.40,
'nachos': 3.45,
'soda': 2.05,
}

reversed_primary_menu = {
6.85: 'veggie sandwich',
2.20: 'extra veggies',
7.85: 'chicken sandwich',
3.20: 'extra chicken',
1.25: 'cheese',
1.40: 'chips',
3.45: 'nachos',
2.05: 'soda',
}

'''
Here is a list of receipts for 9 different orders I've made at the restaurant
'''
receipts = [4.85, 11.05, 13.75, 17.75, 18.25, 19.40, 28.25, 40.30, 75.00]

'''
Constraints:

- you must use 100% of the receipt value, we don't want any money left over
- you can order any quantity of any menu item
- none of the receipt values are "tricks", they all have answers

Find the first combination of food that adds up to the receipt total, print out only one combination for that receipt, and move on to the next receipt.

The output format is up to you, but here are some examples:

4.85:
3 items, extra veggies, chips, cheese

13.75:
3 items, {'veggie sandwich': 1, 'nachos': 2}

Example:
4.85 receipt has three possible combinations:

- best: nachos, chips (2 total items)
- extra veggies, chips, cheese (3 total times)
- chips, chips, soda (3 total items)
  '''

Now with this there can be two solutions.

1. sort the dict
2. straight recursion with remaining amount.
3. The problem here is, one recursion pass is not good enough(if we want multiple same items), ie, i take first item in the dict and try to find recursively the next one that fits the receipt and if anything remaining, go recursively find the element that fits the remaining amount.
4. In above with the recursive calls, I peg first item go to second level, then with the remaining amount check for < 0 which means we dont have elements that fit, then I have to return to second level and now have to move to second item and repeat at second level.
5. I have to do 4) above at first level also.

```py
class Solution:
    def getItems(self, orev: dict, remain: int) :
        rev = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(orev.items()))
        list = []

        for i in rev:
            list = self.getMine(rev, round(remain-i,2))
            if list != [-1]:
                list.append(rev[i])
                return list

        return list

    def getMine(self, rev: dict, remain: int):

        list = []

        if remain < 0:
            retlist = [-1]
            return retlist

        if remain in rev:
            list.append(rev[remain])
            return list

        for i in rev:
            retlist = self.getMine(rev, round(remain-i,2))

            if retlist != [-1]:
                list.extend(retlist)
                list.append(rev[i])
                return list
        return [-1]
```

Second way of doing it is using BST but it has the same thing as above

I feel that this means we are doing n^n.

I am lost on how can I optimize this.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track. The recursion where you know how much $ is left and which item you're on is a great place to start, but instead of just recursing by taking or leaving the current item, recurse while taking 0, then taking 1, then taking 2, and so on and so forth. If at any point you have $0 left over, print how many of the current item you have and return `True`, but if you get to the last item and still can't make it work, return `False`. The time complexity for this will be fuzzy, but it'll certainly work.

You can improve your performance using a technique called *Dynamic Programming*. What you'll do is notice that at any point, if you're looking at item `5` and you have `$5.63` left, you don't care *how* you got there, and can continue solving the problem as if the previous items didn't even exist. Furthermore, if you save your answer for [item 5, money 5.63], if you ever get there a different way, you don't need to do any more work, just instantly return the answer you saved. If you do this, your time complexity will be `O(n*m)`, where `n` is the number of items and `m` is the total number of different allowed money possibilities (in this case, the input money, in pennies). The implementation of this approach is more indepth, but you can google *Dynamic Programming* to get a better sense of what's going on here.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. I will try to look for dyn programming solution for this. Basically if we include that item, how do we get the total. But regarding recursion, Is my approach of looping in the recursion correct? I didnt get what you mean by taking 0, 1, 2. Are you saying this as a loop?

Comment: Just a note on complexity, always consider the worst case scenario

Comment: @JPDF yes its the worst case

Comment: A typical DP approach I see on this interview challenge is to build up a dataset of every combination of foods between 0 and "most expensive receipt" and then use that dataset as a cache/lookup table. This is expensive, computationally, and uses a lot of memory, when you only have a menu of 8 items and a list of 10 receipts. If it was something to persist long term in memory to search thousands or millions of receipts, then DP would be a great approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of my favorite mock interview questions that I ask on interviewing.io where I gave this challenge to OP.

You can solve it with DFS, BFS, DP, or brute force, but the backtracking component is critical to get right. Doing recursion results in less code, and memoization will speed it up, but memoization will be much easier if you do a bottom-up approach (start at $0 and work up to the receipt value) than if you start at the receipt value until you get to 0.

Part one of the problem was "find any answer", part two of the problem is "find the smallest list of items". At this point you can adopt strategies from Coin Change where you take a greedy approach and spend on expensive things first. This won't always give you the best answer right away, but you'll be far closer to the smallest answer than if you sorted the menu by ascending price.

There are other shortcuts that adapt how to solve it quicker by looking at maximum depth principles. For example, if your best answer is 10 items, why build up a whole 20-item list (which still gets you to $0 in top-down, or to the exact receipt amount in bottom-up) only THEN to realize that it's not a "better" answer as a shorter list of items.

Common entry-level approach on part two is to collect "every" answer and find the smallest in the result list, but in a more recent adaptation of the problem you end up with literally millions of combinations and permutations. But if you have an answer of "extra veggies, chips, cheese" you have to find a permutation of "cheese, chips, extra veggies" just to figure out that it's the exact same list in the end.

If we got introduced after our mock interview you should have access to my email address, I'd be happy to stay in contact about this problem and discuss other ideas. Or better yet, you can ask the IIO support team to pair us up again. :)